# How to create a combobox with checkbox items?

Tags: java, combobox

Hello all Java developpers I have developed a simple application with java

```
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
public class Klass {
public static void main(String[] args) {




JFrame frame = new JFrame("My Frame");

//****************** Basic Configuration *****************//
frame.setSize(400, 300);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
//*********************************************************//

JPanel pan = new JPanel();

JComboBox cmb = new JComboBox();

cmb.addItem("Worker 1");
cmb.addItem("Worker 2");
cmb.addItem("Worker 3");
cmb.addItem("Worker 4");

pan.add(cmb);
frame.add(pan);

frame.setVisible(true);


}}
```

But what I want is to make combobox Items displayed as checkbox objects, I want to select more than one worker at once. please help me with your suggestions

Comment: Do you just want a JComboBox where you select multiple items? Why do you need checkboxes to be in a ComboBox, don't you want them to just be by themselves?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your combobox with a custom renderer. Look at the official documentation form Oracle: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html

Comment: thank you very much for your response. I will try your suggestion soon

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a custom cell renderer. By implementing ListCellRenderer.

Answer (score -1):

What you need is JCheckBox, not JComboBox.

```
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Klass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("My Frame");

        // ****************** Basic Configuration *****************//
        frame.setSize(400, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        // *********************************************************//

        JPanel pan = new JPanel();

        JCheckBox cmb1 = new JCheckBox("Worker 1");
        JCheckBox cmb2 = new JCheckBox("Worker 2");
        JCheckBox cmb3 = new JCheckBox("Worker 3");
        JCheckBox cmb4 = new JCheckBox("Worker 4");

        pan.add(cmb1);
        pan.add(cmb2);
        pan.add(cmb3);
        pan.add(cmb4);
        frame.add(pan);

        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Comment: OP's question is clear: a combobox with a dropdown menu, filled with checkbox as options.